# select SQL join query for ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

i am new to SQL and i need help constructing this query.

```
SELECT User_Profile.ProfileId
     , User_Profile.FirstName
     , User_Profile.LastName
     , User_Profile.University
     , User_Profile.Programme
     , User_Profile.Picture
     , User_Friend.status
     , User_Profile.Aboutme 
FROM User_Profile 
FULL OUTER JOIN User_Friend ON
(
    (User_Profile.ProfileId = User_Friend.ProfileId1) 
    AND (User_Friend.ProfileId = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId)) 
    OR (User_Profile.ProfileId = User_Friend.ProfileId) 
    AND (User_Friend.ProfileId1 = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId))
) 

WHERE (User_Profile.FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
```

I think the problem is from the SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId.

Thank you

Comment: I think you will have better luck if you indent this code a little. I was lost after the first `WHERE` clause.

Comment: 922 chars line is a bit difficult to read

Comment: @Steve, what is the exact problem you encounter with the query?

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` doesn't exist in mysql

Comment: Is this `MYSQL` or `SQL-Server`?

Comment: Being that there's both sql-server and mysql tags in this question, and that it's a .NET environment, I'd guess that it's actually sql-server, where FULL OUTER JOIN does indeed exist, though we need confirmation of that...

Comment: Try to break down your problem into smaller pieces.  You may find your own answer and, if not, your question will be easier to understand.

Comment: Ok that is syntactically correct, so the problem must be that it is not returning what you expect.  First we need to understand the db structure and then we need to see what results you would expect to get.

Comment: And while I said it was syntactically correct, that doesn;t mena I woudl wirte it that way even if it was working as that is likley to be a horribly slow query. It is not sargable it has an OR condition in a join and subqueries are usually a bad idea as well. And Ful Outer Joins can be bad if they are not waht you absolutley need.

Comment: Also for the record when you use OR which you shoud not be doing in a join ever, you need to be careful about using parentheses to properly group. Right now the things you probably want grouped together are not.

Comment: That you for your feedback @HLGEM. I am very new to sql and will improve with time

Comment: @HLGEM, the query is not displaying any result it just displays this Executed select............ The CLR type does not exist or you do not have the permission to access it. if i replace SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = %UserId with values (1) it works perfectly

Comment: That is not a SQL server error. Suggest you Google it.  Looks like it is a reporting services or .net error

Comment: have you tried (SELECT **TOP 1** ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be completely misinterpreting your table schema, but it looks to me like you really are trying to do something like this:

```
select 
    ...
from User_Profile up
inner join User_Friend uf
on up.ProfileId = uf.ProfileId1 and uf.ProfileId = up.ProfileId
where up.UserId = @UserId and up.FirstName like '%' + @FirstName + '%'
union all
select 
    ...
from User_Profile up
inner join User_Friend uf
on up.ProfileId = uf.ProfileId and uf.ProfileId1 = up.ProfileId
where up.UserId = @UserId and up.FirstName like '%' + @FirstName + '%'
```

where the "..." is your list of columns. Basically, what I've done is take the complex join conditions and broken them up into two separate queries to help make things clearer.

Also, I have taken the statement "Select ProfileId FROM User_Profile Where UserId = @UserId" and factored this out. This is where I'm not sure of your data and have made a (possibly incorrect) assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem is here:

`User_Friend.ProfileId on (SELECT ProfileId FROM`

This `on` should be changed to either `in` or `=`, I think.

Also, you're missing an AND or an OR here, it seems:

`@LastName + '%')<<<missing something here>>>((User_Profile.ProfileId`

Comment: hi, i have tried = but and IN but none worked

Comment: @Steve Then post the error you're getting and the schema of your table(s).

Comment: @Steve See updated answer. This query is quite messed up (syntactically speaking).

Comment: Thanks, the query worked fine, until i included = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId)) so i am guessing that's where the problem is

Comment: The error message i am getting is SQL Execution Error. Executed select............ The CLR type does not exist or you do not have the permission to access it